How to display mongodb data on tkinter with spark
I'm using pyspark, connected with mongodb and i can use show() to show the table of data, but i'm stuck how to display it on tkinter. Here is the code:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("myApp") \
    .master('local')\
    .config("spark.mongodb.read.connection.uri", "mongodb+srv://user:12345@doan.tyemsow.mongodb.net") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.write.connection.uri", "mongodb+srv://user:12345@doan.tyemsow.mongodb.net") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages","org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1")\
    .getOrCreate()
dataFrame = spark.read\
                 .format('com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource')\
                 .option("uri","mongodb+srv://user:12345@doan.tyemsow.mongodb.net/sample_guides.planets")\
                 .load()
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
r=tk.Tk()
r.title('planet')
r.geometry('1000x300')
frm=Frame(r)
frm.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

r.mainloop()

I tried to use show() but it can't. Please help.

If dataFrame is an instance of pandas.DataFrame, you can use pandastable module to display it using tkinter.  See examples.

I hope this will help.You can use tkinter.ttk.Treeview
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("myApp") \
    .master('local') \
    .config("spark.mongodb.read.connection.uri", "mongodb+srv://user:12345@doan.tyemsow.mongodb.net") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.write.connection.uri", "mongodb+srv://user:12345@doan.tyemsow.mongodb.net") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1") \
    .getOrCreate()

dataFrame = spark.read \
    .format('com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource') \
    .option("uri", "mongodb+srv://user:12345@doan.tyemsow.mongodb.net/sample_guides.planets") \
    .load()

# Convert Spark DataFrame to Pandas DataFrame
pandas_df = dataFrame.toPandas()

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Function to populate Treeview widget with data
def populate_treeview(tree, dataframe):
    # Clear existing data
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
    
    # Insert data into treeview
    for row in dataframe.values.tolist():
        tree.insert('', 'end', values=row)

# Create Tkinter window
r = tk.Tk()
r.title('planet')
r.geometry('1000x300')

# Create frame
frame = tk.Frame(r)
frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

# Create Treeview widget
tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=list(pandas_df.columns), show='headings')
tree.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

# Add headings to the Treeview
for col in pandas_df.columns:
    tree.heading(col, text=col)

# Populate Treeview with data
populate_treeview(tree, pandas_df)

r.mainloop()

